# A Real Talk About Python Software Distribution

Tags: python, installation, pyinstaller, software-distribution

I know this is a hot topic and many people ask this question but I have the feeling I am missing something. What is the proper way to make a python application for end-users? Like, old-school offline .exe and so on. Many users won't touch the terminal/shell and to be honest most software these days is incredibly easy to install. What I know so far:

There are packages out there that can make your software ready for redistribution like

```
pyinstaller, cx_freeze, py2exe
```

I wrote my fairly complex software in like 2 weeks and going crazy for days over making pyinstaller work with my external packages. Is this pain normal? Have I made a mistake by relying on an interpreted language? Because compiling this stuff is mean business. In many other languages you just build the stuff within the IDE and there you go, built.

I am not concerned that my code might be decompiled, so what I have tried is to just create a .bat file with commands to execute my script with my virtual environment(!) python. Can I just manage to have the Python venv in place with my scripts without the user having to install it himself?

Or what is the "usual" way to do this? Use Cython? Or pyinstaller? Praying to the lord of code?

FYI: I am using Python 3.6.8, Windows 8 (don't you dare making fun of me :D) and Pycharm 2019.2

However thank you in advance for your time, regards,
Arjaan

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. This is (a) far too broad and (b) primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

There is no correct or established way of how to create an executable file for your Python project. It's opinion-based.

And how you want to distribute your software is entirely up to you. It can be source code, compiled, as a docker image, through Heroku [One-Click deployment](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-button), debian package, all of the above, ???.
Having choices is nice. Some people need a really simple solution then Heroku or an exe file is nice. Some people are Docker power users, then a multi-arch docker image is nice. Some people want to modify the source code than having the source code is nice. Some people like debian packages and want your project with a systemd service file automatically enabled and started.

You might also not put into the work of getting docker/debian/heroku to work and just tell them a step by step guide on how to get it to run.
Debian and Heroku route might require some periodic maintenance due to the Linux distros updating to newer versions.

There is so much to it and it is an endless discussion where noone is right or wrong.

Comment: I see, I am mostly working on audio-related projects, as I am a full-time audio and event engineer. However, most of my end-users barely manage to install something that is more complicated than drag and drop on mac or runnning an installer, so how can I make this more user friendly because 99% wouldn't want to install any extra software or run code or touch the command line. :)